# (Gtag.js) Google Analytics shows bounce rate 0.0 on 15K users for a custom dimension, which is impossible, is the problem in the code?

Tags: google-analytics, gtag.js

I did create a custom dimension1, abTestDecision=1

I want for certain Website session, to set this with this code:

```
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'UA-xxxxxxx-x', {
  'custom_map': {'dimension1': 'abTestDesign'}
  });

  gtag('event', 'abTestDesign_dimension', {'abTestDesign': 1});
</script>
```

But analytics shows for this dimension abTestDesign=1  a Bounce Rate of 0.0, which is impossible (as this page has a normal bounce of ~70%).

Is the problem somewhere in the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually this situation occurs when you have **duplicate Analytics code** on the page or if you send a **double interaction** (pageview and event) as soon as the user lands on the page.

Your case is the second, you are sending both the pageview and an interaction event upon landing on the page, so the bounce (defined as a session with only one interaction) is inevitably 0.

Try to send the event in this way:

```
gtag('event', 'abTestDesign_dimension', {'abTestDesign': 1, 'non_interaction': true});
```

Comment: no double script, I did change a custom dimension so that it is page-based, will see tomorrow what happens, thanks for trying to help :-)

Comment: I updated my answer, the problem is double interaction, it does not depend on custom dimension.

Comment: what do you mean by double interaction? that is the code that is used for analytics by server if abTestDesign is set to 1. No other analytics code in that case is used at the page. When abTestDesign is set to 0, another analytics code is used.

Comment: You are sending the pageview and the abTestDesign event at the same time, each time the page is loaded you send two interactions at a time.

Comment: I updated my answer, try to send the event with non_interaction parameter.